# How to navigate to Communities's Menu Item with LWC

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm setting a new Salesforce Community with different **Navigation Menu Item** and I'd like to make a **LWC** with a link to one of this custom menu item.

I'm making it with the **Javascript navigation tools** provided by Salesforce. I used the page type **standard__namedPage** as explain in the LWC doc and fill the attributes pageName with the name of my custom navigation item.

```
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__namedPage",
            attributes: {
                pageName: "my-custom-nav-item-name"
            }
        });
```

The result is just an "invalid page" and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have a similar issue. Also, it is comm__namedPage now not standard__namedPage

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any solution yet. @Fawn

Comment: I was able to figure out the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make sure the page reference in the community matches the correct page-type. I think the SF documentation is a little confusing.

This solution worked for me to navigate to a custom record list page in my LWC community page:

```
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'standard__objectPage',
      attributes: {
          objectApiName: 'PMP_Offering__c',
          actionName: 'home'
      },
      state: {
          filterName: 'Default'
      }
  });
```

Also, these solutions worked as well:

```
//Page Reference -- Community Page
                type: 'comm__namedPage',
                attributes: {
                    pageName: this.communityPage
                }
```

```
// Page Reference -- Record Page
                type: "standard__recordPage",
                attributes: {
                    recordId: this.recordId,
                    objectApiName: this.objectPage,
                    actionName: "view"
                }
```

```
// Page Reference -- Object Page
                type: "standard__objectPage",
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName: this.objectPage,
                    actionName: "list"
                },
                state: {
                    filterName: "Recent"
                }
```